# random numbers even,odd,prime

Tags: python, random, primes

```
def FuncA():
    x = 0
    while x < 10:
        Hide = int(random()*1000) 
        if Hide > 99 and Hide < 1000 and Hide % 2 != 1:
            print Hide
            x = x + 1


def FuncB():
    Hide = 0
    for b in range(x):
        if Hide > 99 and Hide < 1000 and Hide % 2 == 0:
            print Hide

def FuncC():
    x = 0
    while x < 10:
        Hide = int(random()*1000) 
    if Hide > 99 and Hide < 1000 and Hide % 2 == 1:
        print Hide
        x = x + 1

def FuncD():
    x = 0
    while x < 10:
        Hide = int(random()*1000)
        if Hide > 99 and Hide < 1000 and Hide % 2 == 1:
            print Hide
            x = x + 1 

def FuncE():
    L = 0
    X = input("Please give me a number : ")
    for S in range(X):
        if X % (S+1) == 0:
            L = L + 1
            print S + 1
    if NumberOfTimesDivided == 2:
        print "The number is PRIME"
    else:
        print "The Number is NOT PRIME"
```

IM try to used random numbers to get 10 numbers of them which each func has to print out 10 different random number. which need help seen if this right or need to fix it. below show what wanted each func to do.

In FuncA     # printing **Random odd number 10** of them in one line

In FuncB     # printing **Random Even number 10** of them in one line

In FuncC     # printing **Random odd 3-digit number 10** of them in one line

In FuncD     # printing **Random Even 4-digit number 10** of them in one line

In FuncE     # printing **Random Prime number 10** of them in one line

my question in this how do get them to print random number for each function i made. in above i wanted them to do a command that would printed random number in one odd, other even, then other in odd 3 digit number, and 4 digit number, lastly prime number. each them must printed out 10 different random number.

Comment: Format your code properly

Answer (score 3):

```
from random import choice
```

10 random odd numbers:

```
>>> print ', '.join(str(choice(range(1, 100, 2))) for _ in range(10))
45, 83, 57, 57, 85, 19, 49, 3, 5, 53
```

10 random even numbers:

```
>>> print ', '.join(str(choice(range(2, 100, 2))) for _ in range(10))
44, 14, 4, 30, 82, 34, 38, 14, 34, 54
```

10 random odd 3-digit numbers:

```
>>> print ', '.join(str(choice(range(101, 1000, 2))) for _ in range(10))
485, 685, 555, 647, 513, 463, 729, 779, 229, 615
```

10 random even 4-digit numbers:

```
>>> print ', '.join(str(choice(range(1000, 10000, 2))) for _ in range(10))
7830, 3496, 3122, 5452, 3982, 7794, 8952, 2492, 4098, 1864
```

10 random prime numbers

```
def pgen(maxnum): # Sieve of Eratosthenes generator
    yield 2
    np_f = {}
    for q in xrange(3, maxnum+1, 2):
        f = np_f.pop(q, None)
        if f:
            while f != np_f.setdefault(q+f, f):
                q += f
        else:
            yield q
            np = q*q
            if np < maxnum:
                np_f[np] = q+q

>>> print ', '.join(str(choice(list(pgen(1000)))) for _ in range(10))
151, 919, 59, 29, 373, 563, 991, 191, 607, 811
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from random import randint as r
from random import choice as c

def FuncA ():
    print (' '.join (str (r (0, 499) * 2 + 1) for _ in range (10) ) )

def FuncB ():
    print (' '.join (str (r (0, 499) * 2) for _ in range (10) ) )

def FuncC ():
    print (' '.join (str (r (50, 499) * 2 + 1) for _ in range (10) ) )

def FuncD ():
    print (' '.join (str (r (500, 4999) * 2) for _ in range (10) ) )

def FuncE ():
    primes = [a for a, b in enumerate (all (c % i for i in range (2, c- 1) ) for c in range (1000) ) if b] [2:]
    print (' '.join (str (c (primes) ) for _ in range (10) ) )
```

With every function the output is 10 random numbers meeting each criterion, and not 10 different random numbers as you stated. If they were 10 different random numbers they wouldn't be random anymore.

Comment: Prime check testing numbers from 2 to c-1 ... seriously? :)

Comment: "Determining primes by trial division ... seriously?" would have been a sensible question.

Comment: So you know you can stop checking at sqrt(c)?

Answer (score 0):

from random import randint 
   def FuncA():

```
   x = 0

   while x < 10:
       Hide = randint(1,1000)

       if Hide % 2 != 0:
          print Hide

          x = x + 1

def FuncB():

   x = 0

   while x < 10:
       Hide = randint(1,1000) 

       if Hide % 2 == 0:
          print Hide

          x = x + 1

def FuncC():

   x = 0

   while x < 10:
       Hide = randint(100,1000) 

       if Hide % 2 != 0:
          print Hide

          x = x + 1

def FuncD():

   x = 0

   while x < 10:
       Hide = randint(1000,10000) 

       if Hide % 2 == 0:
          print Hide

          x = x + 1

def FuncE():

   x = 0

   while x < 10:
       Hide = randint(1,1000) 

       for S in range(Hide):
         if Hide % (S+1) == 0:
            L = L + 1



       if L == 2:
           print Hide
           X + 1
```